# How to make an SQL statement display how many rows it has counted so far?

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose there is a table with billion rows, and I issue a select statement as below,

```
SQL> select * from big_table;
```

During the statement execution is it possible to print the number the rows it has counted and keep updating the counted number?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129437/how-do-i-output-progress-messages-from-a-select-statement

Comment: I haven't found a solution, so maybe it is viable here to write your own function that loads the rows one by one in a variable and meanwhile updates the rowcount each time?